# Progress Bar not loading?

Tags: android

I have a small game I'm working on and I'm trying to have a Progress Bar as an Xp Bar. I have everything set up but the thing won't move

```
private static final int PROGRESS = 0x1;
private ProgressBar mProgress;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private int mProgressStatus;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_screen);

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.xpBar);
    mProgress.setMax(Integer.parseInt(textViewXpNextLevel.getText().toString()));

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int xp = Integer.parseInt(textViewXPValue.getText().toString());
            int XPNEXT = Integer.parseInt(textViewXpNextLevel.getText().toString());
            while (mProgressStatus < XPNEXT) {
                mProgressStatus = xp;

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });   
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

I'm pretty sure everything is set up correctly. But it doesn't load at all? I had this working before  but not it just doesn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your while loop (mProgressStatus < XPNEXT) is going into an infinite loop. How does mProgressStatus or XPNEXT value is going to change after the while loop starts  ? It is not clear in this code.